# JDBC: how to abort connection during the opening stage?

Tags: jdbc, database-connection, abort

That's a simple question. All I want is:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnectionButNoOpen(url)
try {
    connection.open(...
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    ....
}
```

And abort it during opening stage in another thread, as any GUI programs would need.

I have checked the source but it appears the connection is always open before it's returned from DriverManager.getConnection (calling Driver.connect). Is there any standard way I can do this, without resorting to reflection API and hacks?

Comment: Why? For what purpose?

Comment: So I can interrupt it if it takes too long?